# where can i find .so file for x86_64 .so for android studio project so my app can support 64 bit

Tags: java, android-studio, 64-bit, x86-64, .so

i tried to make it arm64 using this code

```
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86' ,'x86_64'
    }
```

but every time i run it in x86_64 CPU it crashes

i want to make an application support 64 bit for all architecture (x86_64 and arm64-v8a) so my questions are :

1# : Can i add libs.so files by copy past method ? if yes where can i find x86_64 lib.so to download it (direct link will be great)

2# : Can i make the app support 64 bit for all CPUs jist by Android Studio ?? if yes please help

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I need this too.